# How to upload a file to an specific folder in Google drive using C#

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Folder ID and a file that I should upload into that gDrive Folder. I have tried the following:

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = titulo; // titulo is a string that contains the tittle of the file
body.Description = descripcion; // the description, it is a string as well
body.MimeType = setMimetype(rutaArchivo); // and this is a method that sets the mimetype according to the file extension.`
```

I try to use `body.Parents` but I have had no luck, `body.parents.add` does not receive only a string (I have tried to give the string containing the gdrive folder id) and I don't really understand the documentation on `parents.Insert`.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a parent reference (you were very close):

```
body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>()
      {new ParentReference() {Id = parentId}};
```

Where `parentId` is the string file ID of the parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As i see it now, it was more a matter of c# sintax lack of knowledge by my part. Thanks very much!